# Uncaught Error: Template parse errors

Tags: typescript, angular5

Please I'm very new to angular. I was following a tutorial and i got this error. I've checked other peoples errors and solution. None saved me.

```
    compiler.js:215 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
   'mat-spinner' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-spinner' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of 
this module.
2. If 'mat-spinner' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to 
the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("

<button mat-raised-button (click)="showAnswer()">Answer Me</button>
[ERROR ->]<mat-spinner [style.display]="showSpinner ? 'block' : 'none'"> 
</mat-spinner>
</mat-card>

"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@21:2
'hi' is not a known element:
1. If 'hi' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this 
module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of 
this component. ("

<mat-card *ngIf="answerDisplay">
[ERROR ->]<hi>{{answerDisplay}}</hi>
</mat-card>

"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@25:2
at syntaxError (compiler.js:215)
at TemplateParser.push../
node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse
(compiler.js:14702)
at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:22709)
at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:22696)
at compiler.js:22639
at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:22639)
at compiler.js:22549
at Object.then (compiler.js:206)
at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:22548)
```

That's the error.
**This is my app.component.html**

```
    <!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
<mat-toolbar-row>
 <span>MyMaterial</span>

<span class="example-spacer"></span>

<button mat-button>About</button>
<button mat-button>Services</button>
<button mat-button>Contact</button>
</mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>

<mat-card>
<mat-form-field>
<input matInput[(ngModel)]="answer" placeholder="Enter something..">
</mat-form-field>

<br>

<button mat-raised-button (click)="showAnswer()">Answer Me</button>
<mat-spinner [style.display]="showSpinner ? 'block' : 'none'"></mat-spinner>
</mat-card>

<mat-card *ngIf="answerDisplay">
<hi>{{answerDisplay}}</hi>
</mat-card>
```

**material.module.ts**

```
    /**
     * Created by regina on 05/15/2018.
 */
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
MatButtonModule, MatCardModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, 
MatProgressBarModule,MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
imports: [MatButtonModule, MatToolbarModule, MatInputModule, 
 MatProgressBarModule, MatCardModule, MatFormFieldModule],
exports: [MatButtonModule, MatToolbarModule, MatInputModule, 
 MatProgressBarModule, MatCardModule, MatFormFieldModule]

  })

   export class MaterialModule { }
```

As i said earlier, I've checked questions like my own on here...none could solve my problem. Most solutions given has already being in my code. I needed to learn about angular material. 
Please any help will much appreciated. I'm so stuck!
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

import **MatProgressSpinnerModule** t use mat-spinner .

see docs https://material.angular.io/components/progress-spinner/api

```
    /**
     * Created by regina on 05/15/2018.
 */
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
MatButtonModule, MatCardModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, 
MatProgressBarModule,MatToolbarModule ,
MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
imports: [MatButtonModule, MatToolbarModule, MatInputModule, 
 MatProgressBarModule, MatCardModule, MatFormFieldModule,
 MatProgressSpinnerModule],
exports: [MatButtonModule, MatToolbarModule, MatInputModule, 
 MatProgressBarModule, MatCardModule, MatFormFieldModule,
 MatProgressSpinnerModule]

  })

   export class MaterialModule { }
```

Comment: still getting error but this time is: `Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'hi' is not a known element:
1. If 'hi' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("

<mat-card *ngIf="answerDisplay">
  [ERROR ->]<hi>{{answerDisplay}}</hi>
</mat-card>`

Comment: in this file app.component.html  change ```<hi>{{answerDisplay}}</hi>`` to   ```<p>{{answerDisplay}}</p>```

Comment: it's not neccessary to change hi to p tag. you can change it to any known html tag

Comment: another error please help `ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'matInput[(ngModel)]' is not a valid attribute name.
    at EmulatedEncapsulationDomRenderer2.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.DefaultDomRenderer2.setAttribute (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:113460:16)
    at BaseAnimationRenderer.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/animations.js.BaseAnimationRenderer.setAttribute (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:111937:23)`

Comment: I think I had solved your current question. Do post new Question because it's quite difficult to write the solution in the comment.

Comment: Wow! Its working now i added a space to `matInput[(ngModel)]` so it became `matInput [(ngModel)]`

Answer (score 3):

Add **`MatProgressSpinnerModule`** under **`AppModule.ts`**

```
 import {
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatProgressBarModule,
  MatProgressSpinnerModule,
} from '@angular/material';
```